# Silverlight 4 is not debugging. Symbols are not loaded

Tags: silverlight, debugging, visual-studio-2010

I am making my first silverlight application. I only put a textbox and a button. I tried to debugged and It doesn't work.

I tried going to the web project. property pages->start options->debuggers and silverlight is already checked. so I need help.

Why is not working????

Thanks

Nora

Comment: I also found a questions that the guy said that I have to compile the library that it is open, then Which Library, where is silverlight located?

Comment: I changed to Internet explorer as default browser, and now I can debug. still I wanna know why frefox doesn`t work, if I have seen many post that people use firefox

Answer (score 2):

You need to disable out-of-process hosting for silverlight.

Go to about:config in Firefox, look for key "dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.npctrl.dll" and set the value to false (doubleclick).

Comment: hi. how can I put you as the answer. thanks a lot. it did it.

Comment: @nora77: there is a check mark where the answer score is, check it to mark the answer as accepted. You can also give it a vote up.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Firefox? There is an issue with the recent Firefox update. You have to make SL to be in-proc plugin. By default plugins run out-of-proc and VS does not see them.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this Issue.
what i Did is as follows

Just Go to Properties of .web project and mark the checkbox against Silverlight.
Now "Start Debugging".

May Be this would be helpFul.