# Symbols not loading for Silverlight app on VS 2010

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-3.0

Hi I have a silverlight application pointing to Silverlight 3. I use VS 2010 Ultimate. When i run it in debug mode or attach to process, break points will be highlighted with yellow exclamations saying symbols are not loaded. I tried the solution given here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/7bf5a77b-c30d-4674-a8fc-c8fe46ce676b

It points to a pdb file on Framework's temp folder and says Symbols loaded. I tried to load the symbols manually by going to Symbol Settings. Even that did not help. Any idea how to fix?

Comment: Are you using Firefox? If so, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115276/silvelight-4-is-not-debugging-symbols-are-not-loaded/3217714#3217714)

Comment: I ve Firefox 3.6 and IE 8 both have same effect.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I re-installed Silverlight tools but that didn't help. It seems to work for some silverlight projects on my machine, but doesn't work for one particular project. Are you having the issue with all silverlight projects, or just one in particular?

Comment: i copied a project from another machine which did not debug. then i created a new project, created new classes, pasted the code. That also didn't help.. :(

Comment: This one is working for me: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430192/silverlight-4-vs-2010-debug-symbols-not-loading/8154696#8154696

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this works but this is how i got it working.

I went to Tools> options> debugging

unchecked "Require source files to exactly match the original version"

Comment: Did not help me. I have still on the search for what always works.

Answer (score 6):

Another step to take when Silverlight debugging doesn't work is to clear the cache of the browser.

Also make sure the properties in the web project hosting silverlight has silverlight debugger enabled. Web -> Debuggers -> Silverlight checked.

Comment: That did not help.. :( All the break points are flagged with exclamation.. so there is no way hitting it without loading the symbols i believe..

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me:

1. Remove the Silverlight project from my Web project
2. Clear the Browser Cache for IE
3. Go to the folder where IE stores its cache and delete Silverlight*.js
4. Add the Silverlight project reference back to my Web project
5. Rebuild and start debugging

Answer (score 0):

Mostly it happens due to mismatched version of Silverlight and SDK. Uninstall both, and install it. I hope that helps.

Comment: That might be a possible reason. I have SDK 3 and i could not find a browser addin for version 3 on microsoft site. at office cn't download from other sites. I observed that if there is a runtime error on the code, it breaks and after that we can debug properly... its a temporary solution..!

Comment: I tried installing/reinstalling everything including Visual Studio from scratch and nothing helped...!

Answer (score 0):

You can try starting a new instance.

Right click to Web Project, select Debug, Start a new Instance.

Comment: Hi Amit, can you try the following...

Save your solution, from property pages of the Web project, remove silverlight application. Change Target framework to version 3.5. Save. Change framework to version 4.0, add silverlight application from project property pages. Rebuild.